# error requesting state by id = finalized: Get "http://localhost:3500/eth/v2/debug/beacon/states/finalized"

Tags: synchronization, ethereum, checkpoint

experts :)
im trying to run the prysm to sync beacon nodes to check my sepolia testnet account balance which i got some sepolia testether from sepolia faucet to the account.

and for using sync from checkpoing, according to this process below, i had some issues.
"https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/prysm-usage/checkpoint-sync"

the command of the above web-page:
./prysm.bat beacon-chain --checkpoint-sync-url=http://localhost:3500 --genesis-beacon-api-url=http://localhost:3500

i got error about this command.
**Error retrieving checkpoint origin state and block: error requesting state by id = finalized: Get "http://localhost:3500/eth/v2/debug/beacon/states/finalized": dial tcp [::1]:3500: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

so instead, i put public beacon chain checkpoint sync endpoint's url like this to solve the previous error:
./prysm.bat beacon-chain --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:8551 --jwt-secret=jwt.hex --checkpoint-sync-url=https://beaconstate-sepolia.chainsafe.io --genesis-beacon-api-url=https://beaconstate-sepolia.chainsafe.io

and i got error about this command.
**Error retrieving checkpoint origin state and block: error detecting chain config for finalized state: version=0x90000072 not found in any known fork choice schedule: unable to find requested BeaconChainConfig**

i just have followed the prysm manual for syncing from checkpoint(cause sync full nodes takes too long time).
how can i solve this and finally sync beacon nodes, and check my account balance??

thank you for your advice!!!

im trying to run the prysm to sync beacon nodes to check my sepolia testnet account balance which i got some sepolia testether from sepolia faucet to the account.

Comment: Put a bounty, but I need answers to solve this problem on a private blockchain